# Split data in Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba, split, cell, mac-address

a) Write VBA code that takes a user-provided MAC address from cell C7

b)Displays the portion of the MAC address that identifies the manufacturer of the hardware network
adapter, with colons, and centered in cell C10.

c) Displays the portion of the MAC address that identifies the manufacturer of the hardware network
adapter, without colons, and centered in cell C11.

d) Displays  the  portion  of  the  MAC  address  that  identifies  the  serial  number  of  the  hardware
network adapter, with colons, and centered in cell D10.

e) Displays  the  portion  of  the  MAC  address  that  identifies  the  serial  number  of  the  hardware
network adapter, without colons, and centered in cell D11.

f) Cells B7, B10, B11, C9, and D9 should display the labels shown in Figure 1. These labels need
to be displayed in BOLD type.

g) Your sub procedure should end by selecting cell C7.

h) Assign  your  (main)  sub  procedure  to  a  rectangular  shape  button  labeled  “MAC  Address
Information”.

I need a VBA Excel code to split data in Cells.

***This was the final looks like***
[image]

Thanks so much

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: [C7].TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Comment: this is my tries however, its not works for me to split the MAC address

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: You can use the VBA `Split` function to split into individual elements, and then use the `Join` function to put the two halves together with or without colons as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get your Manufacturer number, you just want to write the first 8 characters of `C7` to `C10`:

`Range("C10").Value = Left(Range("C7").Value,8)`

To remove the colons, you would use Replace

`Range("C11").Value = Replace(Range("C10").Value,":","")`

I'll let you work out what to do with `D10` and `D11` but here's a hint: *you don't want the* `Left`..